# Save and load data automatically in Unity WebGL build

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I want to store data in unity WebGL build. The playerprefs has only 1MB capacity.
I don't want the user load the data after each time open the site and want to cache them like playerprefs.
Is there anyway to increase the capacity of playerprefs or is there any other way to cache data in webgl build?

The data that i want to cache is asset bundles that user can download them based on his use, and manually add them to application. and i don't want that user to this process each time open the site.

Answer (score 1):

In the WebGL Publishing Settings there is a check for Data caching.

This enables the build to use the browser cache to store its files. So returning users won't have to download your files again.